# Mongoid: aggregation framework works in scope?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, aggregation-framework

I have following method working in ruby. Basically it uses aggregation framework to pick top k deals ordered by daily sold quantity, in active US deals. Deal is a collection in MongoDB.

```
  def top_daily_quantity(k)
    match = { "$match" =>
                  {
                      country: "US",
                      active: true
                  }
    }
    project = {
        "$project" => {
            _id: 1,
            sold_quantity: 1,
            days: {"$divide" => [{"$subtract" => [Time.zone.now, "$start_at"]}, 3600*24*1000]}, #note days is in float
            daily_quantity: {
                "$divide" => [
                    {"$multiply" => ["$sold_quantity", 3600*24*1000]},
                    {"$subtract" => [Time.zone.now, "$start_at"]} # this difference is in ms
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    sort = { "$sort" => { daily_quantity: -1 } }
    limit = { "$limit" =>  k}
    collection.aggregate([match, project, sort, limit])
  end
```

The thing is I want to change it into scope so that I can chain lots of scopes together for a complex query with flexibility. I simply changed to the format below:

```
scope :top_k, lambda { |k|
    ... # the same method body as uppoer
       }
```

Then I got errors below:

```
1.9.3-p385 :001 > DS::Deal.top_k(3)
```

NoMethodError: undefined method `to_criteria' for #<Array:0x007fb96f35e3c0>
    from /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/mongoid-3.1.5/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:292:in`merge!'
    from /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/mongoid-3.1.5/lib/mongoid/criteria.rb:277:in `merge'
    from /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/mongoid-3.1.5/lib/mongoid/scoping.rb:305:in`top_k'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in`start'
    from /Users/x/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/railties-3.2.14/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in`require'
    from script/rails:6:in `'

That's because the last line returns an array which breaks the requirements for scope. From http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html it seems I can only use map reduce for this purpose, but I want to check here to see if I missed anything.

Comment: Did you ever find how to get this to work? I'm stuck in the same situation.